# Home Network split after wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to setup a wireless router in my home network. I want to use the bandwidth limiting function in the router, but I think you must run it through the WAN port to use it.
But when I uplink through the WAN port on the wireless router it changes the subnet(I think that's what it is called) from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.1,  I get internet, but I can not access my local resources that are on 192.168.0.1
Is there are way to join these 2 networks together? Is there a better way to do this? Or maybe there is a better way to limit the bandwidth?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: "you must run it through the WAN port to use it."  That is how it works on my own Wireless Router. If you have just the one router, ask the ISP to put the Modem in Bridged Mode and then you can hook up the WAN port on your wireless router and use the bandwidth limiting function.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I want to limit only the Wifi users bandwiddth. I do not want to limit users upstream of the wifi router. Thank You.

Comment: In my router the Wi-Fi use can be constrained by user (MAC address of the user's machine). But the overall limit is to the WAN.

Comment: do you want to throttle their speed or limit their total bytes over time?

Comment: I will like to throttle the speed.  The wireless router method is working for throttling, but the only problem is everything after the wireless router is on 192.168.1.x and everything before is on 192.168.0.x, so the devices on each network cannot talk to each other.  That is because the throttling is done through the WAN port on the router, and it resigns the network IP addresses to 192.168.1.x

Comment: Is there some magical way to join the 192.168.0.x network with the 192.168.1.x network. Like some kind of network rainbow bridge.